# recorrer datagridview y obtener todos los datos de la primera celda selecionados con el checkbox

Tags: c#, mysql

logre hacer que capture codigo de la celda seleccionados con el checkbox
pero solo puedo selecionar una ,quisiera poder aplicar (EnviarPorSeleccion) para todo los checkbox seleccionados

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rows in datalistado.Rows)
            {


                        string id = datalistado.Rows[rows.Index].Cells["TipoSerieCorrelativo"].Value.ToString();

                        obj.EnviarPorSeleccion(id);
                        listarTOdo();

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

segun entiendo tu problema , la solucion deberia ser la siguiente

```
foreach(GridViewRow gvRow in gvwDatos.Rows)
            {

                if(((CheckBox)gvRow.FindControl("MicheckBox")).Checked)//con esta validas si el checkbox esta seleccionado
                {
                    string id = gvRow.Cells[0].ToString();//Posicion de la celda en la grilla, empieza desde cero y solo puedes obtener los valores de estas columnas tipo BoundField

                    obj.EnviarPorSeleccion(id);
                    listarTOdo();
                }

            }
```